# Choosing bootstrap capacitor for MOSFET driver

Tags: h-bridge, bootstrap

I have [IRS2011](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irs2011pbf.pdf) high/low side MOSFET driver, for driving [IFRZ44N](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irfz44n.pdf) MOSFETs configured in H-bridge. How would I calculate the bootstrap capacitor required by the IC for driving high-side?

I am aware of the equation in [this pdf](http://www.irf.com/technical-info/appnotes/an-978.pdf), but since these wont drive the H-bridge continuously I dont know what to use for the frequency. I am driving a motor with the H-bridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You control the frequency so you should know exactly what it is.

The bootstrap capacitor power cannot be used if you require DC drive from the H-bridge. Each half-bridge must be driven low frequently to 'refresh' the capacitor, or the charge will leak off and the drive to the high-side n-channel MOSFET will be compromised.

If you need to drive it high continuously you must use a different type of power such as a DC-DC converter.

Comment: Ohh, so bootstrap capacitor can be used only if the H-bdrige gets "refreshed" in a fixed amount of time?

Comment: Yes, that's a gotcha with this kind of driver.